# Wamp Installation on Windows 7 32bit plain setup

Tags: windows-7, installation, wamp

How to resolve "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll" missing dll error?

Comment: Read [WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) section called ___--- Visual C++ Packages ---___ and make sure you have them all installed

Comment: any update? Have you installed now WAMP?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [Universal C Runtime (Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True).